# Does CodeIgniter set_userdata automatically escape data?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

CodeIgniter [suggests](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/security.html) you escape all data before inserting into the database. It provides [three ways](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html) to do so.

When CodeIgniter is configured to store sessions in the database via `$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;`, when does CodeIgniter's automatic data escaping fire when it encounters a piece of code like `$this->session->set_userdata($data)`?

Answer (score 0):

No you do not need to escape the data saved in a session. The Session class uses the Active Record Class to interface with the database and the Active Record class makes it so you do not have to escape your data as it states in the first paragraph here.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html